# vbscript checking if program is running. says its always running, even when its not

Tags: vbscript, taskmanager

I have been having issues keeping an important application running all the time. I tried making a script to monitor when its down, record it, and attempt to bring it back up However my script says this application is running even when it is closed and not listed in task manager details. (windows 10) How do I get this to work?

```
'~ Create a FileSystemObject
Set objFSO=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'~ Provide file path
outFile="C:\" & Day(Date) & "-" & Month(Date) & "-" & Year(Date) & "_" & Hour(Now) & "-" & Minute(Now) & "-" & Second(Now) & "_Results.txt"

'~ Setting up file to write
Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(outFile,True)

strComputer = "."
strProcess  = "CheckInNet.exe"
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Command = "C:\Program Files\Procare\Client\CheckInNet.exe"



Function IsProcessRunning( strComputer, strProcess )
    Dim Process, strObject
    strObject   = "winmgmts://" & strComputer
    count = 0
    IsProcessRunning = False
    For Each Process in GetObject( strObject ).InstancesOf( "win32_process" )
        If UCase( Process.name ) = UCase( strProcess ) Then
            IsProcessRunning = True
            count = count + 1
            wscript.echo "check: " & IsProcessRunning
            'Exit Function
        End If
    Next
    wscript.echo "check: " & IsProcessRunning & ". # of proccesses detected: " & count
End Function
If IsProcessRunning(".",strProcess) = False Then
    objFile.WriteLine Day(Date) & "/" & Month(Date) & "/" & Year(Date) & " " & Hour(Now) & ":" & Minute(Now) & ":" & Second(Now) & " 1st check is down"
Else
    objFile.WriteLine Day(Date) & "/" & Month(Date) & "/" & Year(Date) & " " & Hour(Now) & ":" & Minute(Now) & ":" & Second(Now) & "1st check is UP"
End IF
While (true)
    If IsProcessRunning(".",strProcess) = False Then
    stringDate=Day(Date) & "/" & Month(Date) & "/" & Year(Date) & " " & Hour(Now) & ":" & Minute(Now) & ":" & Second(Now) 'generate Date 
        wscript.echo stringDate & " DOWN"
        '~ Write to file
            objFile.WriteLine stringDate & " DOWN"
        wscript.Sleep(12000)
        If IsProcessRunning(".",strProcess) = False Then
            objFile.WriteLine Day(Date) & "/" & Month(Date) & "/" & Year(Date) & " " & Hour(Now) & ":" & Minute(Now) & ":" & Second(Now) & " Attempting to open"
            WshShell.Run Command 'attempt to re open it
            wscript.Sleep(20000)
            If IsProcessRunning(".",strProcess) = False Then
                objFile.WriteLine Day(Date) & "/" & Month(Date) & "/" & Year(Date) & " " & Hour(Now) & ":" & Minute(Now) & ":" & Second(Now) & " Still Down"
            Else
                objFile.WriteLine Day(Date) & "/" & Month(Date) & "/" & Year(Date) & " " & Hour(Now) & ":" & Minute(Now) & ":" & Second(Now) & " UP"
            End IF
        Else
            objFile.WriteLine Day(Date) & "/" & Month(Date) & "/" & Year(Date) & " " & Hour(Now) & ":" & Minute(Now) & ":" & Second(Now) & " Came up on own"
        End If
    End If
    wscript.Sleep(900)
Wend
objFile.Close
```

The program is called CheckInNet.exe while running in Task manager Details(for all users) and is the same name in its installation folder.  The program works fine if I swap out the CheckInNet.exe to another program like cmd.exe. but CheckInNet.exe always shows one process running. Please help, why would it do this?

Comment: Why not to run executable with [`WScript.Shell` ActiveX `Exec` method](http://ss64.com/vb/exec.html) and then monitor the state via `oExec.Status`?

Comment: If I run your script and change CheckInNet.exe to notepad.exe it works. What is CheckInNet.exe? Are you sure you have correct permissions?

Comment: @omegastripes Didn't know about that. Still learning. I'll give it a try. Thank you.